# Locate the remaining directory entries in Ext2 that don't fit in the block

Tags: directory, operating-system, filesystems, osdev, ext2

I'm developing my own operating system and currently, I'm working on the Ext2 file system driver. I'm using the GRUB files for testing. I'm stuck with listing a directory. I'm reading the first block of the directory's contents and everything is just fine, but there aren't a lot of them! At the end of the block, it is filled with zeroes. However, when I mount the disk image and list it in Ubuntu, I can see that there are extra files.

How can I get these directory entries? Any suggestions?